# Lego NXT-ROS working on Groovy Galapagos?

Tags: ros, nxt, nxt-ros, lego, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm just wondering does anyone know if the NXT-ROS package is compatible with the Groovy Galapagos release? There doesn't seem to be any documentation except the wiki and that recommends using the diamondback release(with electric being the newest release even mentioned.) Also are there any other packages that anyone could recommend to control a Lego NXT Robot?
Thanks in advance,
Tadhg Fitzgerald.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52836/lego-nxt-ros-working-on-groovy-galapagos?/) by [Tadhg Fitzgerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/4009/tadhg-fitzgerald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tadhg Fitzgerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/4009/tadhg-fitzgerald/) on 2013-02-01**:
I'll answer this since nobody else did; the answer is no, if you are using NXT-ROS you should use the Electric release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Old, but just saw it.
Here I modified NXT for Groovy

https://github.com/maxsieber

---

Originally posted by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) with karma: 181 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-29**:
Nice! Do you plan to make an announcement, integrate it into ROS wiki etc.? If it's at too early stage to "announce", then I'd suggest to start discussion in SIG like [ros-sig-edu](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-education).

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-07-30**:
I'm trying to use the compass with this if you can help me please let me know.

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-08-01**:
I will add my repo to the wiki soon.
As my modifications where very minor, I dont think we a need a SIG.
I started a related Question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/67831/is-there-a-newer-nxt_ros-stack-using-nxt-python-222-instead-of-120-on-raspberry-pi/

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-08-01**:
@boog I don’t have a compass, also no Gyro IR or Color for further Testing :-(
You could try to build your compass like the AccelerometerSensor(DigitalSensor) and by looking in a newer version of nxt-python. If it works, Send me a Pull Request plz

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-08-01**:
I got it to work by combining a patch I found here https://code.google.com/p/foote-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=24 my files are a mess otherwise would send you.

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-08-01**:
Do I have to do anything special to get yours working on a raspberry pi? Thanks.

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-08-01**:
I did not look at the issues, my nxt-python version problem is also a Issue(15) there. It should work on the RPi. I only modified sensor car for my needs. Tell me if it works, or what your errors are.

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-08-08**:
@msieber, the nxt_msgs won't compile and neither will nxt_ros as it looks for an x86 lib in /usr/lib during rosmake. Any idea how to fix this? (On rpi).

**Comment by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) on 2013-08-12**:
which lib ?